# Using VDD with Drupal 6 site

Tags: 6, installation, virtual-machine

I'm trying to get a Drupal 6 site up and running with the [Vagrant Drupal Development](https://www.drupal.org/project/vdd) project.

I can get VDD going.. get my site installed, the database imported etc.. but I need to make VDD use an old version of PHP. I see some instructions online that say you can set which PHP version to use, but it isn't happening.. it doesn't say where in the json the setting needs to appear.

I tried with the following json, but it ended up as `PHP Version 5.4.39-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2` :

```
{
  "php": {
    "version": "5.2.17"
  },
  "vm": {
    "ip": "192.168.44.44",
    "memory": "1024",
    "synced_folders": [
      {
        "host_path": "data/",
        "guest_path": "/var/www",
        "type": "default"
      }
    ],
    "forwarded_ports": []
  },
  "vdd": {
    "sites": {
      "drupal6site": {
        "account_name": "root",
        "account_pass": "root",
        "account_mail": "box@example.com",
        "site_name": "drupal6site",
        "site_mail": "box@example.com",
        "vhost": {
          "document_root": "drupal6site",
          "url": "drupal6site.dev",
          "alias": ["www.drupal6site.dev"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Who or what is VDD? Please EDIT your question to explain this acronym and/or add a relevant hyperlink ...

Comment: oops missed that part.. edited

Comment: OK, next recommended edit: '... some instructions online ...': please share the url of that also ...

Answer (score 1):

VDD of  8 version doesn't support the feature of [changing PHP](https://www.drupal.org/node/2113559) version. You may try other Vagrant box for Drupal. For example [this](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm) one, it has very good documentation.

Comment: So on the [site](https://www.drupal.org/project/vdd) where it says "Note, VDD works great with Drupal 6, 7 and 8." it is incorrect? The link you provided mentions that it *is* possible to change PHP version

Comment: You can install Drupal 6 on VDD, but you can't change PHP version. The last comment on the page says "As it appears it's really hard to maintain this feature. 8.x-1.x branch most likely will not support it. Anyway after releasing stable 8.x version 7.x branch will be removed. So, I propose to leave this issue as "won't fix"."

Answer (score 0):

After having issues with both [vampd](https://github.com/vampd/drupal) and [vdd](https://www.drupal.org/project/vdd) I used a [Turnkey](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/) linux iso for my virtualbox.  They have one with [Drupal 6](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/drupal6) but I am using the Drupal7 one.  Installs easily, configures one NAT adapter but you have to do the Host-only adapter yourself.  Either start from the site they give you or replace it with your own existing site.  I renamed the /var/www/drupal7 site folder and then did a `ln -s my.git_cloned.site drupal7` to just sym link my site (managed in git) to the existing apache configuration.  Comes with phpmyadmin out of the box.